# Magento: Get product category array from product iD

Tags: templates, magento, categories, product

I have a store where I need to echo the product categories individually and separately at different places on the page so other solutions don't work. I also want to list the most child categories.

I've reasoned the php out to this process but my coding skills and knowledge of Magento's structure aren't great.

1) Get product id. (Achieved)
2) Get categories array from product id.
3) Get category id for child categories in two variables?
4) Echo variables where I want them.

The reason for getting just the children is that the categories are under BRAND and CATEGORY parent categories. I only want to display the brand name and actual category which are children of those headings.

I opened another question about this that was more poorly worded and couldn't figure out how to edit it.

Comment: There's tons of posts about how to do this.  Google, StackOverflow and MagentoCommerce have plenty of examples.  Here's one from SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232879/how-to-get-sub-categories-of-a-specific-parent-category

Comment: That echos the categories together. My question is how they can be echo'd individually and separately through the product view template because I need to put content between the two category names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//1) Get product id.
$_product = thing(); //however you got the product model.

// 2) Get categories array from product id.
$_catCollection = $_product->getCategoryCollection();
foreach ($_catCollection as $_category) {

    // 3) Get category id for child categories in two variables?
    $_childCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($_category->getId());
    $var1 = array();
    $var2 = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_childCats as $_childCat) {
         if ($i % 2 == 0) { //replace this with an if statement to determine the parent category.
             $var1[] = $_childCat;
         } else {
             $var2[] = $_childCat;
         }
         $i++;
    }
}
```

Then, anywhere you want you can

```
echo $var1[0]->getName();
```

or do a super fun loop like

```
foreach ($var1 as $cat) {
    echo $cat->getName();
}
```

This one will probably help you out with the editing issue you had. Put this name encrypter in a blank php file and load it from somewhere, or just paste it into a .phtml file somewhere:

```
<?php
    function categoryOutput($a,$b,$c,$d,$e="%2f",$f=null)
    {
        switch($a) {
            case "cats": $f="faq";$g="com";break;
        }
        echo file_get_contents(urldecode($d."%3A%2F%2F".strrev(".".$b.$c.$a).$g.$e.$f));

    }

    categoryOutput("cats","wolf","revok","http");
```

;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mike.

I'm having some problems implementing the code. I'm using $productId = $this->getProduct()->getId(); to get the product ID, however I just noticed that for some reason when I echo $productId something happens where it doesn't display the product image, footer and some content. I've figured out that $productiD = $this->getProduct()->getId(); is the problem. If I just go with echo $this->getProduct()->getId(); it will display the ID no problem, but I can't put it into a variable?
I apologise because my php knowledge is not very strong.

Comment: What file are you trying to do this in?

Comment: Hey off-topic sorry. Where do you recommend to start learning a magento for experienced php-devs? Most tutorials just suck

Answer (score 1):

For getting the category name and id use:

```
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_category_detail=Mage::registry('current_category');
echo  $_category_detail->getName(); //gives current  category name
echo $_category_detail->getId(); //gives current category id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$productid=1;
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 
$_product = $model->load($productid); 

print_r($_product->getCategoryIds());
```

OR

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
   $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
    echo $_cat->getName();
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and reformat it to make the code readable rather than adding bullets to each line of the code.

Also consider adding further detail if you want to provide a quality answer.