# magento category search

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I have two main child under navigation in category tree as below images

[image]

[image]

I want to list category and subcategories for either **Region** or **Activities**, I have tried two different function for that

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name')->load();
    foreach ($collection as $cat) {
        echo $cat->getName();
    }
```

this will return all child from both Region and Actities and another function

```
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(10);
foreach ($children as $category) {
  echo $category->getName();
}
```

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232879/how-to-get-sub-categories-of-a-specific-parent-category)

this return only subcategories

I want to list all category, sub-categories and sub-subcategory and so on... for Region

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    $rootcatId= 10;
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($rootcatId);
    function  get_categories($categories) {
        $array= '<ul>';
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
            $count = $cat->getProductCount();
            $array .= '<li>'.
            '<a href="' . Mage::getUrl($cat->getUrlPath()). '">' .
                      $category->getName() . "(".$count.")</a>\n";
            if($category->hasChildren()) {
                $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($category->getId());
                 $array .=  get_categories($children);
                }
             $array .= '</li>';
        }
        return  $array . '</ul>';
    }
    echo  get_categories($categories);
```